# printing string in c using a pointer

Tags: c, string

I was just printing some characters in C.
I have declared char c and assigned its characters.
then using a for loop i try to print the characters one by one.
I have used pointers, of course.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{ 
  char c[4] = {"hia"};
  int i; 
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  { 
    printf(&c[i]);
  }
  return 0; 

}
```

However when I compile my code using turbo, i get output "hiaiaa" instead of "hia"! What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Your `printf()` call is broken. You are using the string (from the point you specify) as the formatting string. This will not print single characters. Instead each call will print from where its formatting string starts, to end of the string.

This means the first call will print all of `c`, the next will print from `c[1]` and onwards, and so on. Not at all what you wanted.

If you want to print single characters, use the `%c` format specifier:

```
printf("%c", c[i]);
```

No pointer necessary, since the character is passed by value to `printf()`.

Comment: @Bathsheba I like to think that's how I roll. :) At least most of the time.

Comment: i know my question was kinda silly, but pointer is something i have always had difficulty with, its one of the things of C i dont really have a firm grasp on

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` function have an `char*` as first argument, that's correct. However, it prints a *string* (that is, a zero-terminated sequence of `char`) so it will always do that.

If you want to print one character at a time, then you have to use that format, like in:

```
printf("%c\n", c[i]);
```

You also have another problem, and that is that you try to print the zero terminator as well. This character is not printable so will not show. Use e.g. `i < strlen(c)` as the loop condition to overcome this.

Also, instead of printing character-by-character, print it all as one string:

```
printf("%s\n", c);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what happened in your loop:

```
0. hia
1. ia
2. a
3. \0
```

However, you want to print exactly one `char` at a time, not a null terminated `string`, so you should pass it as `char` not a `char*`:

```
printf( "%c", c[i] )
```

Also, you are looping four times, but string length is just three. You should use:

```
for( i = 0; i < strlen( c ); i++ )
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

1) For loop size should i<3 , not i<4 (i=3 refers to the null character at the end of the string)

2) use printf("%c",c[i]);

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of what you're seeing: In each loop, `printf` is printing a null-terminated string. This string starts in every loop one char later inside your array.
How it should be done, depends on what you're intending. If you want to print the string char by char via pointer you may use:

```
char *p=&c[0];
while (*p) {
  printf("%c", *p);
  p++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will call `printf` with the following parameter:

```
printf("hia");  // first loop iteration
printf("ia");   // second loop iteration
printf("a");    // third loop iteration
printf("");     // fourth loop iteration
```

You probably meant to print one character at a time:

```
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)  // No need to print the string termination character.
  { 
    printf("%c", c[i]);  // "%c" is the printf format code to print a single character 
  }
```

Comment: I am interested to know how and why `printf(&c[i])` is a valid syntax?

Comment: @haccks `printf` expects a `char*` as its first argument. `&c[i]` (the address of a `char`) is a `char*`. Since the string doesn't contain any format specifiers, no additional arguments are expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is to *print string using pointer*. You could use

```
printf("%s", c);
```

or character by character as (include library *string.h* for this)

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(c);i++)
{ 
   printf("%c", c[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in C strings are stored as character arrays and are terminated by a zero-value, so called zero-terminated strings. Btw, this is why you have to make the array size of 4 for thee real chars.

In your example, you are passing pointers th each char to the printf function and printf prints the strings from your pointer to the next null-value . The 1st pass prints "hia", the 2nd ia and the 3rd a.

To print a single char in each pass, you have to use

```
printf ("%c", c[i]);
```