# Is printf(c); is a valid syntax (where c is a string literal)?

Tags: c, syntax, arguments, printf, format-specifiers

I came to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20395310/2455888) and see this line

```
printf(&c[i]);
```

I want to know that, is this a valid syntax ? Printing a string/string literal without format specifier `%s` does't cause **undefined behavior** or **constraint violation** ?
And if this is a valid syntax then in what purpose it is used ?

I compiled this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *c = "Hello World";

    printf(c);
    printf("\n\n");
    printf(&c[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

and it compiles without giving any warning/error with output

```
Hello World

Hello World
```

Comment: Which compiler do you use that doesn't emit warnings on seeing this code?

Comment: @devnull; GCC 4.8.1, compiled with flag `pedantic`, `Wextra`, `Wall` in C99 mode.

Comment: GCC 4.4.3 with -wall option gives `warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments`

Comment: @Dayalrai; But on my compiler it is not giving any warning/error!

Comment: @haccks yes i saw your first comment. I was just informing.

Comment: @devnull Actually why to forbid printf("just do it\n");

Answer (score 3):

It's unwise (particularly if said string came from a user), but it's not illegal.

The clause in question would be section 7.19.6.1, paragraph 3 (emphasis mine):

> The format shall be a multibyte character sequence, beginning and ending in its initial shift state. The format is composed of **zero or more directives**: ordinary multibyte characters (not %), which are copied unchanged to the output stream; and conversion specifications, each of which results in fetching **zero or more subsequent arguments**, converting them, if applicable, according to the corresponding conversion specifier, and then writing the result to the output stream.

You should either use `fputs(c);` or `fprintf("%s", c);` to make sure your string isn't accidentally interpreted to contain directives.

Answer (score 1):

It works but is not recommended.  Suppose you had

```
char *c = "We have a 30%sale!";
```

Then your `printf` statements would be accessing garbage memory trying to resolve the `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `printf` is a prime example of *unsafe* code: The correctness of your program cannot be determined from the source code (and specifically the *type system*) alone; correctness depends on *values* rather than *types*. The fact that such code is possible makes C an "unsafe language". Example:

```
void f(char const * p)
{
    printf("%s", p);      // this is safe!

    printf(p);            // correct if the string contains no format specifiers;
                          // undefined behaviour otherwise
}
```

To repeat: The correctness of your program depends on its runtime characteristics, and cannot be guaranteed statically.

You should never write such code!

Comment: Kerrek, I amazed it is allowed in C! I think this is a loop hole.

Comment: @haccks: loop hole? In C you can do basically anything you want, and this is by design. What can't be done is just because the compiler doesn't understand what operations you want to do, not because it doesn't want you do do something.

Answer (score 0):

It's allowed but it's risky. Consider some function as below.

```
void foo(const char* s) {
    printf(s);
}
```

It might generate a core if something like `%s` is in the input argument.

Answer (score 0):

It works because `c` is a pointer to start of string (in other words it is pointer to first sign of your string). `c[0]` lets you a char `W`. And `&` let's you pointer to this `char`. The construction such you used in code just gets the value by pointer and immediately returns the pointer of this value. For example `c[i]` is equal to `*(c+i)`.

Why it works? Because `printf()` function receives a pointer to string as argument. And it prints all sign starting from pointer up to `'\0'` sign.

Please learn more about pointers in C language and how C-arrays and C-string are implemented.

Comment: I am learning pointers, arrays and string and their implementations and that's why I asked. :)